# Unity3d & Google Glass

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-glass

I'm trying to get the gestures from the google glass to an unity app, that I'm developing but I can't detect the swipe gestures, also I tried to make a plugin to get this, but I'm not so expert on developing to accomplish this, so any one has done this(get glass gestures into unity)?

Comment: Google Glass has certainly been made to work with Unity. So you might be better off showing us what you have tried to do, and tell us how it didn't work. Then it might be easier to point out the error or help you along with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AndroidInput.GetSecondaryTouch() static method to get touches on the Glass touchpad. 
You can easily detect individual taps with AndroidInput.touchCountSecondary.